# Алгоритм: все возможные целые из наборов от .. до

Tags: рекурсия, комбинаторика, алгоритм, javascript

Вроде простая задача, но что-то лыжи не едут.

Дан массив диапазонов — пар мин. и макс. значений. Только **целые** числа.

Нужно найти все возможные целые, получаемые суммированием «допустимых» значений из произвольного комплекта идущих **подряд** диапазонов, по одному из каждого участвующего.

Например, дано три диапазона:

```
[{"min":1,"max":2},{"min":3,"max":4},{"min":5,"max":6}]
```

Можно получить числа `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`.

На деле пар больше, значения веселее. Может, есть известный красивый алгоритм?

В общем смысл моего, далеко не оптимального, [решения](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/BNMeQ/4/), такой (перебор):

1. распаковать пары min:max до массивов допустимых значений `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`
2. перебирать массивы слева направо;
3. для каждого варианты глубины вправо от 0 (только себя), до правого края;
4. перебрать все возможные комбинации значений между этими массивами, по одному зн. из каждого. Суммировать, уникальные значения сохранить в результат.

**Интересно ещё решить обратную задачу:** даны опять эти пары, и число. Разложить его в идущие подряд допустимые значения.

Усложнённая условием про «подряд» [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)? Подскажите, как называются алгоритмы для похожих задач?

Comment: лучше бы привели код, было бы сразу понятно что хочется, а-то я что-не могу пару переходов осилить. как из примера в результате получается 2 ? типа 2=2,2+2=4,2+2+2=6,3=3,3+2=5,3+2+2=7 ?

Comment: @eicto: 2 получается, если использовать только один из диапазонов.

Comment: Немного улучшил алгоритм: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/BNMeQ/). В каждый сет добавляю элемент =0, и пробую все возможные комбинации сумм, беря по одному элементу из каждого сета.

Не годится этот вариант тем, что не учитыват, чтобы сеты, участвующие в сумме, шли **подряд**.

Можно как-то улучшить? Похоже, задача чем-то похожа на [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: а почему просто не складывать текущий  и предыдущий массив ? я имею ввиду такую штуку - получаем следущую сумму и складывыем е с предыдущей. попробую написать, но я слегка не в форме...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Складывая два интервала [a,b]+[c,d] получим итервал [a+c,b+d], если интервалов больше то будет [a1+a2+...+an,b1+b2+...+bn]. Таким образом мы избавляемся от лишних вычислений, в частности от рекурсии совсем. Нам достаточно знать для каждой комбинации интервалов сумму их минимумов и сумму их максимумов.
Чтобы перебрать все комбинации интервалов будем двигать границы в списке интервалов. Т.е. сначала будем смотреть первый интервал, потом первый и второй, потом с первого по n-й, затем второй, со второго по третий и т.д.

```
var a = [{"min":2,"max":3},{"min":2,"max":2},{"min":2,"max":2}];
var a_l = a.length;
var res = [];
for (var i=0;i<a_l;i++){//левая граница списка интервалов
    for(var j=i;j<a_l;j++){//правая граница списка интервалов
        var vmin = 0;
        var vmax = 0;
        for(var k=i;k<=j;k++){//бежим по комбинации интервалов
            vmin+=a[k].min;
            vmax+=a[k].max;
        }
        for(var a_v=vmin;a_v<=vmax;a_v++){
            if (res.indexOf(a_v)<0)
                res.push(a_v);
        }
    }
}
res.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/whWpq/)

ЗЫ Дальнейшая оптимизация что для последующих комбинаций достаточно добавлять только те элементы, которые меньше минимума в результате и больше максимума в результате, тогда и res.indexOf не нужен будет.

Comment: Этот алгоритм подразумевает, как я понял, что результат это интервал, но например такие данные на входе  

    [{"min":2,"max":3},{"min":50,"max":51},{"min":100,"max":101}]
Должны вернуть  

    [2,3,50,51,100,101,52,53,54,102,103,104,150,151,152,153,154,155]

Comment: @ReinRaus ну ссылку на фидл дал же. пробуйте. результат - это кусочный интервал. будет верный ответ.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, извините- не заметил ее

Comment: Вот что значит подойти к задаче с умом, а не в лоб решать :)  
Несомненно это гораздо лучший алгоритм.

Comment: То, что результат будет кусочным (в общем случае) оптимизировать (по поводу ЗЫ) будет сложнее, и возможно без необходимости. Тут замечание верно, да.

Comment: Такой же подход и у меня. Только более запутанно. У вас чисто-прозрачно получилось. Перечитал код. Гениально! : )

Answer (score 3):

вот такое решение не подойдет ?

```
var ranges=[{"min":2,"max":3},{"min":1,"max":20},{"min":3,"max":5},{min: 2,max: 10}];
//var ranges=[{"min":2,"max":3},{"min":2,"max":2},{"min":2,"max":2}]
function range2array(range) {
    var ret=[];
    for (var i=range.min;i<=range.max;i++) ret.push(i);
    return ret;
}

function arrays_summ(array1,array2) {
    var ret=[];
    if (array2===undefined) return array1;
    for (var i in array1) 
        for (var n in array2) 
          ret.push(array1[i]+array2[n]);
    return ret;
}

function process(ranges) {
    var lastarray;
    var result={};
    for (var i in ranges) {
        lastarray=arrays_summ(range2array(ranges[i]),lastarray);
        for (var n in lastarray) result[lastarray[n]]=1;
    }
    return result;
}
function keys2array(hash){
    var ret=[];
    for (var i in hash) {
        ret.push(i);
    }
    return ret.sort(function(a,b) {return (a*1)>(b*1)?1:-1;})
}
console.log(keys2array(process(ranges)));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mhT5Z/

Comment: Не совсем въехал в код. Но по тесту он даёт неверный результат:
`[{"min":1,"max":2},{"min":3,"max":4},{"min":5,"max":6}]` вернул ряд `["1","2","4","5","6","9","10","11","12"]` где например, пропущено 3, которе может быть получено сольным значением из второго диапазона.

Выложил своё доделанное «[решение](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/BNMeQ/4/)» которое выводит все итерации.

Comment: Немного подпилил и упростил код @eicto. Теперь выдает корректный результат. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/DZQPN/

Comment: я навереное  задачу не до конца понял...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DZQPN/5/ можно еще так упростить, правда тогда надо работать с копией ranges. можно копию сделать до рекурсии в той-же функции а рекурсию в замыкание сложить.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, так понятнее. [Упаковал аккуратнее](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/DZQPN/6/) : )

@eicto: проявляется красота кода! Рекурсии хороши. Разбираюсь в примере.

Comment: @sergiks, хотя это какая-то неправильная рекурсия получается. Я ее вообще сделал в стиле эрланговской хвостовой рекурсии с аккумулятором, но не для эрланга это лучше оформить как цикл.

Answer (score 1):

Пример здесь http://jsfiddle.net/8cdez/7/
Осталось только обернуть в красивую функцию, но само решение не очень красивое, плюсики ответу не ставьте, пожалуйста. Пусть будет.

```
test=[{"min":2,"max":3},{"min":2,"max":2},{"min":2,"max":2}];
res=new Array();
for (var x=test[0].min; x<=test[0].max; x++) {
    for (var y=0; y<=test[1].max; y++ ? y!=0: y=test[1].min) {
        for (var z=0; z<=test[1].max; z++ ? z!=0: z=test[2].min) {
            res.push(x+y+z);
        }
    }
};
res.push(test[1].min+test[2].min);
res.push(test[1].max+test[2].max);
res=_.unique(res.sort());
alert(res);
```

Используется UnderScore (функция unique).

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо за вариант. Тут как раз то, чего хотел избежать: кол-во вложенных циклов в коде зависит от числа сетов. А его нужно сделать динамическим. Может, всего две пары min-max, а может, 6 подряд.

Совсем не нужна библиотека для уникальных значений, достаточно вставлять новых кандидатов однострочной функцией, что-то типа:

    function addUnique( arr, val){
        if( arr.indexOf(val) == -1) arr.push( val);
    }